# The Convergence of Coordinate Descent involving multiple variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

Given a convex, but not differentiable function $f:  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into two parts, namely, $f(x) = g(x) + \sum_{i=1}^n h_i(x_i)$, where $g$ is convex and differentiable, and each $h_i$ convex, then we can use coordinate descent to find a minimizer. Here, the $h_i$ should be separable, and the above theorem has been proved.

Now, I want to solve a problem, which involves multiple variables. Assume the objective function is:

$$
\min f(D, \alpha) \equiv \frac{1}{2} || x - D \alpha||^2_F + \lambda ||\alpha||_1  
$$

If I use coordinate descent to optimize the above objective function by starting from all of the coordinate components of $\alpha$, then the coordinate components of $D$. Repeat the cyclic update process until convergence.

My problem is that can I apply the above separable property to the above objective function to prove that I can find a minimizer and converge by using coordinate descent algorithm? If not? How to prove the convergence when an objective function involving multiple variables and some of them are combined by multiplication?
(When I focus on $\alpha$, the first part is a convex and differentiable function, while the second part is a separable convex function. On the other hand, when I update $D$, the problem is a convex and differentiable function.)

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question but you can type \| for norm, e.g. $\|\alpha\|_1$ instead of $||\alpha||_1$. The spacing just looks better that way.

Comment: Your problem is not convex because $g(D,\alpha)=\frac12\|x-D\alpha\|_F^2$ is not jointly convex in $D$ and $\alpha$. For example, suppose $D^*$ and $\alpha^*$ are such that $D^*\alpha^*=x$. Then $g(D^*,\alpha^*)=0$ and $g(5D^*,0.2\alpha^*)=0$, but their convex combination has $g(3D^*,0.6\alpha^*)>0$ because $(3D^*)(0.6\alpha^*)=1.8x\ne x$.